# shrink uilabel background to fit allotted space

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, xcode5, uilabel

To set the background of my UILabel, I use

```
theLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blah"]];
```

Now my problem is that the background image is actually bigger than the size of my UILabel. Is there a simple way to make the background shrink to the size of the UILabel?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I finally figured it out

```
- (void)reziseLabelBackgound
{
    UIImage *rawImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blah"];
    CGSize bkgSize = self.myLabel.bounds.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bkgSize);
    [rawImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,bkgSize.width,bkgSize.height)];
    UIImage *bkgImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    self.myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:bkgImage];
}
```

Comment: ahhh, I was just writing how you can draw image in a rect. good catch.

Answer (score 1):

Edit - misunderstood question.

No, label is unable to do that. You'll probably need to use a transparent label with an UIImageView underneath with same size as the label and `contentMode` set to value you need.